# Why Group by is working unexpectedly in JPQL eclipseLink?

Tags: eclipselink, jpql

Here is my query (jpql-eclipseLInk) -

```
"SELECT NEW com.nrbwlko.officeprojectmaven1.dao.ProjectProgressDao(c.projectMemberFk.projectMember,"

                + "COUNT(c),"
                + "CASE (c.materialDetailFk.materialType.materialType) WHEN 'plate' "
                + "THEN SUM(c.componentLength*c.componentWidth*c.materialDetailFk.unitWeight*c.projectMemberFk.memberQty*c.projectMemberFk.projectUnitIdFk.unitQty)/1000000 "
                + "ELSE SUM(c.componentLength*c.materialDetailFk.unitWeight*c.projectMemberFk.memberQty*c.projectMemberFk.projectUnitIdFk.unitQty)/1000 END, "
                + "CASE (c.materialDetailFk.materialType.materialType) WHEN 'plate' "
                + "THEN SUM(c.componentLength*c.componentWidth*c.materialDetailFk.unitWeight*c.projectMemberFk.memberQty)/1000000 "
                + "ELSE SUM(c.componentLength*c.materialDetailFk.unitWeight*c.projectMemberFk.memberQty)/1000 END, "
                + "CASE (c.materialDetailFk.materialType.materialType) WHEN 'plate' "
                + "THEN SUM(c.componentLength*c.componentWidth*c.materialDetailFk.unitWeight*c.projectMemberFk.fabricatedQty)/1000000 "
                + "ELSE SUM(c.componentLength*c.materialDetailFk.unitWeight*c.projectMemberFk.fabricatedQty)/1000 END, "
                + "CASE (c.materialDetailFk.materialType.materialType) WHEN 'plate' "
                + "THEN SUM(c.componentLength*c.componentWidth*c.materialDetailFk.unitWeight)/1000000 "
                + "ELSE SUM(c.componentLength*c.materialDetailFk.unitWeight)/1000 END) "
                + "FROM CuttingList c "
                + "WHERE c.projectMemberFk.projectUnitIdFk.projectId.projectId = :id "
                + "GROUP BY c.projectMemberFk.projectMember"
```

First Sum is the Total sum (consisting of groups by members obviously) --- which is not equal to the sum of individual  row . When i group by individual row id (c.id) Total is 28193 (which is correct value i checked it manual calculation) But when i group it by member value is 28103.

I tried various combination and unless each  row is individual total value is always less than actual value. It's part of my android app backend, all work is done except this data mismatch which makes my last 6 month work useless. I desperately need help.

One more information i would like to share that if i group it by Material (query provided below) then Total value is again correct, for example

Here is another query from same table Giving correct Total Material Weight but this time it grouped by material and not by member

```
"SELECT NEW com.nrbwlko.officeprojectmaven1.dao.MaterialSummeryByProjectDao(c.materialDetailFk.materialName,COUNT(c),"
                + "CASE (c.materialDetailFk.materialType.materialType) WHEN 'plate' "
                + "THEN SUM(c.componentLength*c.componentWidth*c.materialDetailFk.unitWeight*c.projectMemberFk.memberQty*c.projectMemberFk.projectUnitIdFk.unitQty)/1000000 "
                + "ELSE SUM(c.componentLength*c.materialDetailFk.unitWeight*c.projectMemberFk.memberQty*c.projectMemberFk.projectUnitIdFk.unitQty)/1000 END) "
                + "FROM CuttingList c "
                + "WHERE c.projectMemberFk.projectUnitIdFk.projectId.projectId = :id "
                + "GROUP BY c.materialDetailFk.materialName"
```

giving me material grouped in 4 type and total is 28193 (correct value)

(Count(c) in both case is correct which is 6 nos)

here is the result when i grouped by material -- (Total is correct)
I can provide more information if required.

[image]

Comment: What is the SQL generated from your query that is executed from the DB? That might be an easier spot to notice what is going wrong and why some results aren't included. Otherwise, your JPQL is far too complex to understand what you are doing; simplify it as much as possible to debug what is going wrong.  First guess is that you have an inner join filtering results somehow